# Is my website is too slow?

Tags: seo, performance, page-speed

I checked the speed of my website with http://tools.pingdom.com/ .

**Results:**

```
Per. Grade = 85/100
Req.s = 18
Load Time = 1.94s
Page Size= 96kb
```

Is this result is good for my website(also consider SEO)?

Comment: Load time looks rather slow for the page size. how long are resources taking to load?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to anything wrong with the speed of the page you ran through the tool but that's only returning the load results for that page don't forget.

Aside from anything else, your question is pretty broad. Hundreds of factors contribute to the speed of page loading and even more factors contribute to the performance of a page in organic search (SEO) so not really sure how else we can help you.

Comment: Please don't ask a question which should be closed. If you could vote to close the question instead, it would be perfect.

Comment: I presume you meant 'answer' not 'ask' - I did vote to close it as well.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "answer" of course.